# Datetime is opened by default

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]

[image]

Why my **ion-datetime** is opened by **default** ?.. Help me Please

Comment: Are you saying that you would like there to be a field showing the selected date, and when you click on it open the selection?

Comment: I need calendar close by default